# Upward expanding Accordion TableView in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to implement an "accordion" TableView in iOS, something like in [this link](https://github.com/ennioma/EMAccordionTableViewController).
But one small change, I would like the TableView to be at the bottom of the screen, and have the sections expand **upwards** instead of **downwards**.

I would like this to be supported in iOS7 and up. Support for iOS6 would be nice to have, but not mandatory.

I've been searching for a solution for the last 3 days and tried many different libraries, but no luck. Any ideas on how to implement something like this? Is this something that's possible to do with any library I use? Or do I need to find something with that specific functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this one library I had Used for something same..https://github.com/vicpenap/VPPDropDown

Comment: I ended up using this one: https://github.com/klevison/KMAccordionTableViewController
I modified it to have one section open all the time, and set all the sections to be the same size to achieve the desired effect.
But yours was pretty close to what I was looking for, so I accepted your answer. Thanks!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely possible.
I don't know whether there is a framework but I can suggest you using simple inserting of table view rows. 
[Apple doc on table view](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html)

But you will definitely need an advanced table row management